# Amserial Chart Legends

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using amserial charts, for this i've 3 values. I've used this
But it doesn't  work.

```
`var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();`
```

`chart2.addLegend(legend);`

`legend.valueText= "val";`

I've 3 values. I want lables like this -

-Computer
-Laptops
-Tablets

Please suggest me, what should i do for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
legend.valueText = "-[[value]]"; // graph value (current chartCursor selection)
legend.labelText = "-[[title]]"; // graph title
```

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueText
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#labelText

Comment: When I use the above mentioned property on the legend it does not work. I used it like legen.valueText = "state". The value of state comes from the web service. Any suggestions on how I could use it.